# Running ARIMA-SEATS with different weekdays

Tags: r, arima, parameterization

Is it possible to run the Census Bureau's ARIMA X-13 SEATS with, say Sunday-Thursday as working days, or Sunday-Friday, for that matter?

I'm running in R with the 'seasonal' package, if that matters.